# JavaScript and MediaQuerys

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make some responsive page begin by mobile first and i'm always coming back to the same mistake.

When I have my pull-down menu in mobile version the menu it's ok, but when I try to change it to no-mobile version it doesn't works. i'd like a mobile version with one column and when the windows size oversteps the mark of 400px modify to two columns.

This is my code after lots of changes.

```
$('.slide ul').slideUp();

var ventana;
ventana=$('.wrapper').width();
$(window).on('load',preguntaTamano());

$(window).resize(preguntaTamano());


function preguntaTamano(e){
    if(ventana<400){
      mobile();     
    }
    else if(ventana>400){
      noMobile();
    }
}


function mobile(e){
    $('.especial').hide();      
    $('.toggle').on('click',controlaMenu);  

}

function controlaMenu(e){
    $('.slide ul').slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault(); 
}

function noMobile(e){
    $('.lista').show();

    var listaElegidos;
    listaElegidos= $('.elegidos').html();
    $('.especial').preppend(listaElegidos);     
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try posting a demo http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce the issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/laurita133/cbySc/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use CSS media queries instead:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .lista {
    display: block;
  }
  .especial {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 401px) {
  .lista {
    display: none;
  }
  .especial {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Comment: lots of thanks, this isn't exactly i was looking for, but it helped me a lot to become my solution.